# Conversion form string to float shows error (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have joined two columns in my csv dataframe

```
df[C] = df[A] + df[B]
```

df[A] has values of the type ID00007637202177411956430

df[B] has numbers as values including negative integers (e.g -4)

I joined these two by an underscore so the resultant value I get is  ID00007637202177411956430_-4

Now I want o convert this column into float and I have tried :

```
x = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(df["C"]))
```

But I keep getting the error

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "ID00007637202177411956430_-4" at position
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: "ID00007637202177411956430_-4" what is your expected output for this? String contains alphabet so you can not convert into numeric

Answer (score 0):

your error shows that df [A] and df [b] are strings.
addition does a concatenation, you cannot convert a string containing alpabetic or special characters to numeric

convert db[B] and df[A] to numeric before addition.